# TypeError: string indices must be integers <-- How do I?

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

My code:

```py
import pandas_datareader.data as web

all_data = {ticker: web.get_data_yahoo(ticker)
            for ticker in ['AAPL', 'IBM', 'MSFT', 'GOOG']}
```

The error when I execute it:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-27-dc1fe894f539> in <cell line: 1>()
    ----> 1 all_data = {ticker: web.get_data_yahoo(ticker)
      2             for ticker in ['AAPL', 'IBM', 'MSFT', 'GOOG']}

    3 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas_datareader/yahoo/daily.py in _read_one_data(self, url, params)
    151         try:
    152             j = json.loads(re.search(ptrn, resp.text, re.DOTALL).group(1))
--> 153             data = j["context"]["dispatcher"]["stores"]["HistoricalPriceStore"]
    154         except KeyError:
    155             msg = "No data fetched for symbol {} using {}"

   TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I'm beginner.
I'm studying with the book: Python for Data Analysis (Orelly)

Comment: Have you tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://www.learnpythonwithrune.org/fix-get_data_yahoo-from-pandas-datareader/) It recommends to update the version of pandas_datareader you are using to 0.10.0 or later.

Answer (score 0):

This package seems deprecated as the [last commit was on Mar 17 2022](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/commits/main) and [has around 120 active issues](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues).

Sorry to say it but, you may consider another resource to learn from that does not require a package to be constantly updated with an API or is actively maintained.

You may read this blog for more tips on how you can pick a good package:
https://medium.com/plumbersofdatascience/how-to-find-a-good-python-package-2fd3abbb20f1

Good luck!